# PHP & XML - How to generate a soap request in PHP from this XML?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am completly new to SOAP operations.

I have been provided with an XML document (SOAP) to get some collection points for a shipping method.

From the manual located here:

http://privpakservices.schenker.nu/package/package_1.3/packageservices.asmx?op=SearchCollectionPoint

I can see that I need to use the following SOAP request:

```
POST /package/package_1.3/packageservices.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: privpakservices.schenker.nu
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://privpakservices.schenker.nu/SearchCollectionPoint"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SearchCollectionPoint xmlns="http://privpakservices.schenker.nu/">
      <customerID>long</customerID>
      <key>string</key>
      <serviceID>string</serviceID>
      <paramID>int</paramID>
      <address>string</address>
      <postcode>string</postcode>
      <city>string</city>
      <maxhits>int</maxhits>
    </SearchCollectionPoint>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The thing is that i don't know how to send this as a request using PHP, and how to get the response.

Any help to pinpoint me in the right direction, is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I can read the response data with var_dump. However, I am not able to read individual element data.

I need to read data as below

```
foreach($parser as $row) {
  echo $row->customerID;
  echo $row->key;
  echo $row->serviceID;  
}
```

Comment: google php soap, or even better: search for soap in the php manual.

Comment: please accept your answer in a day or two. that will mark your question as solved. thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If anyone should be interested, i have provided the correct answer:

```
$soapUrl = "http://privpakservices.schenker.nu/package/package_1.3/packageservices.asmx?op=SearchCollectionPoint";

$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap12:Body><SearchCollectionPoint xmlns="http://privpakservices.schenker.nu/"><customerID>XXX</customerID><key>XXXXXX-XXXXXX</key><serviceID></serviceID><paramID>0</paramID><address>RiksvŠgen 5</address><postcode>59018</postcode><city>Mantorp</city><maxhits>10</maxhits></SearchCollectionPoint></soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
"POST /package/package_1.3/packageservices.asmx HTTP/1.1",
"Host: privpakservices.schenker.nu",
"Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
"Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_post_string)
); 

$url = $soapUrl;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
$response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);

$parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);
```

Comment: what to do if you need to put dynamic values in the $xml_post_string like customer id for example?

Comment: as that is string you can always append this way `$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" ..... <maxhits>' . $myVar . '</maxhits>.... ?>';`

Answer (score 5):

following example might help you.

**SOAP XML schema**

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">
        <x:Header/>
        <x:Body>
            <web:NumberToDollars>
                <web:dNum>10</web:dNum>
            </web:NumberToDollars>
        </x:Body>
    </x:Envelope>
```

**PHP code**

```
  $wsdl = 'http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso?WSDL';


    try{
        $clinet=new SoapClient($wsdl);

        $ver =array("dNum"=>"2002");
        $quates=$clinet->NumberToDollars($ver);

        var_dump($quates);


    }

    catch(SoapFault $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```