# PHP - How to read data from SOAP XML

Tags: php

I have code for read XML SOAP 1.2 from web service. 
Im using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18580428/2629513

I get this code below:

```
 SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[OdkazyResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [OdkazyResult] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [odkazy] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [odkaz] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [kod_zbozi] => 31400001
                                                [typ] => OBR1
                                                [popis] => Oki ML 280 - foto
                                                [url] => http://www.atcomp.cz/katalog/31400001/ML280.gif
                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [kod_zbozi] => EC376123GB
                                                [typ] => OBR1
                                                [popis] => Malý obrázek
                                                [url] => http://www.atcomp.cz/katalog/EC376123GB/lq-680_-_maly.jpg
                                            )

                                    )

                                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [kod_zbozi] => EC376123GB
                                                [typ] => OBR2
                                                [popis] => Velký obrázek
                                                [url] => http://www.atcomp.cz/katalog/EC376123GB/lq-680_-_velky.jpg
                                            )

                                    )
```

And how I can read the [kod_zbozi], [typ], [popis], [url] attributes? I need to save it into my mysql database (this is not problem, the problem is read the data from this format XML). Thanks.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I edited. I added link to the answer what I using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the very first thing you might want to do is to convert that object into an array (to avoid naming problems)

You can use this function to do that:

```
  function object2array($object) { 
    return json_decode(json_encode($object), true); 
  }
```

then something like this:

```
$data = object2array(simplexml_load_string('....'));

print_r($data); // Its regular array now, use it keys to access values, then simply insert them into db
```