# Send XML in soap request and attach certificate PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap

I am trying to implement an SOAP API. But I am not getting how to send request to the given URL.

I do not have any support for that API, just have few lines as an instruction.

I did not used SOAP before, can some one please help to understand how to create and send request as XML using a certificate.

**Here is the instructions to use the API**

```
Test API Link
https://202.82.66.148:8443/ptms4541/ws/CksServices

Worksite：BST-API
Account：BST-API01

Response to connect (Have to set header of the following)

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<soap:Header> 
<tns:RequestSOAPHeader xmlns:tns="https://202.82.66.148:8443/ptms4541/ws/CksServices"> 
<tns:account xmlns="https://202.82.66.148:8443/ptms4541/ws/CksServices">BST-API01</tns:account> 
<tns:timestamp xmlns="https://202.82.66.148:8443/ptms4541/ws/CksServices">201606211538</tns:timestamp> 
<tns:pwd xmlns="https://202.82.66.148:8443/ptms4541/ws/CksServices">***********</tns:pwd> 
<tns:worksite xmlns="https://202.82.66.148:8443/ptms4541/ws/CksServices">BST-API</tns:worksite> 
<tns:discount_id xmlns="https://202.82.66.148:8443/ptms4541/ws/CksServices"/></tns:RequestSOAPHeader> 
</soap:Header> 
<soap:Body> 
<ns2:getShippingLine xmlns:ns2="http://ws.service.gen.cks.com/"/> </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>

Certificates to installed attached in Email

getShippingLine()
```

Along with this I have an file that have `.crt` extension

I have tried `CURL` (from here : [PHP & XML - How to generate a soap request in PHP from this XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572550/php-xml-how-to-generate-a-soap-request-in-php-from-this-xml)) and also `SoapClient` (did not understand how to create request in required format : [Sending XML input to WSDL using SoapClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595789/sending-xml-input-to-wsdl-using-soapclient)) to implement this but no luck.

Actually I am unable to understand that how to send request and what need to be send in that request in which manner.

Please help me to understand this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Php SOAP library does not support certificates and private key assertion as well wse-php rob richard library done so well for this case , i have to come this solution after long time :

```
 function Curl_Soap_Request($request, $url)
{
    /**
     * @param request is your xml for soap request 
     * @param url is location of soap where your request with hit
     */

    $keyFile = getcwd() . "\\privatekey.pem"; //
    $caFile = getcwd() . "\\certificate.pem"; //
    $certPass = "test123";
    // xml post structure

    $xml_post_string = $request; // data from the form, e.g. some ID number

    $headers = array(
        "Content-type:  application/soap+xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Accept: text/xml",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        // "SOAPAction: '/Imp1/ApplicantEligibilityService",
        "Content-length: " . strlen($xml_post_string),
        ); //SOAPAction: your op URL

    //$url = $soapUrl;

    // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // The --key option - If your key file has a password, you will need to set
    // this with CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD
    //  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,  $keyFile);

    // The --cacert option
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT,  $caFile);

    // The --cert option
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $certPass);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword); // username and password - declared at the top of the doc
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    // converting
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;

}
```

Comment: also you can solve this by following this link : http://zrashwani.com/wcf-ssl-service-with-php/#.V8Ato6KN2tY